# Discrepancies between bounce rate and drop rate in behavior flow

Tags: google-analytics, bounce-rate, bounce

The bounce rate of one of my websites 15%, however when looking at the Behavior Flow section of Google Analytics, it shows a homepage drop off of around 80%

Can a visitor be counted as a non-bounce, yet show as dropping off the homepage in the Behavior flow report?

I appreciate if a user stays on the homepage for >30mins it will not be counted as a bounce, however I don't believe this to be the case in my situation.

We have >1000 hits/day so the data is fairly concrete.